# Facing an issue with code using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 10 checkboxes, if I select 5 checkboxes the rest should be disabled and if I select less than 5 remaining should be enabled. How to do it using JavaScript?

This is my code:

```
var count = 1;

function myfun(obj) {
    debugger; /*var x = req.body.checkbox; if (x == undefined) { x = false;}*/
    if ((obj.checked) == true) {
        count++;
    } else if ((obj.checked) == false) {
        count--;
    }
    if (count > 5) {
        c1.disabled = true;
        c2.disabled = true;
        c3.disabled = true;
        c4.disabled = true;
        c5.disabled = true;
        c6.disabled = true;
        c7.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add here a code, you have written so far?

Comment: var count=1;
function myfun(obj)
{ 
debugger;
/*var x = req.body.checkbox; 
if (x == undefined) {
    x = false;}*/ 

 if((obj.checked)==true)
  {
      count++;
  } 
else if((obj.checked)== false)
{
 count--;
}  
  if(count>5)
  {
    c1.disabled= true;
    c2.disabled= true;
    c3.disabled= true;
    c4.disabled= true;
    c5.disabled= true;
    c6.disabled= true;
    c7.disabled= true;
  }
}

Comment: @SivakrishnaBhagavatula welcome to stackoverflow. Please be mindful when commenting/posting. Remember that you can edit your post when needed and remember **please** to use code formatting when showing your code. The mess you have in the comment is completely unreadable - and it prevents other users from helping and/or learning.

Comment: please edit your post and update your code there with proper comments so that It is easy to read instead of pasting your code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

from the problem described i have derived a solution. See it it works for you 
https://jsfiddle.net/oL48u5ew/1/

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="visit"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
var count = 0
$('.visit').change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
    count++
  else
    count --
  if(count > 4)
  {
  $('.parent').find('.visit').each(function(){
    if(!this.checked){
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
  })
  }
});
```

Comment: for some reason the link you have provided is not working for me

Comment: Thanq...  But i dont know jquey .... Will you please forward the code in js